# Long Running ETL Process - Background Jobs, Spark, Hadoop

Tags: ruby, hadoop, apache-spark, background-process

I have a scenario in an application where;

1. Have to load data from multiple sources (more than 10)
2. Mostly sources are HTTP/JSON Web Services and some FTP
3. Have to process those data and put into a central Database (Postgresql)

Current implementation is done in Ruby using Background jobs. But I see following issues in it;

1. Very high memory usage
2. Jobs stuck sometimes without any error report
3. Horizontal scaling is tricky to setup

Does in this scenario, any way Spark or Hadoop can help or a better option.

Please elaborate with some good reasoning.

Update: 
As per comment, I need to elaborate it further. Here are the points why I thought to Spark or Hadoop.

1. If we scale the concurrency of running jobs, that also increase heavy load on DB server. I had read though, that Spark and Hadoop are build to face such heavy load even on DB side.
2. We can't run more background process then the physical cores of CPU (as recommended by ruby and sidekiq community)
3. Concurrency in Ruby is actually dependent on GIL, which is not actually real concurrency supported. So each job can fetch single central data source, if that stuck into an IO call then the source will be locked for it.

All above points considered to be part of builtin architecture of Hadoop & Spark. So I was thinking over lines to look into these tools.

Comment: This is a strange question. I work in a place that uses Ruby, Spark, and Hadoop and I can tell you that they're not architecturally interchangeable like that. Regardless of whether a hadoop-based solution is overall more appropriate for your situation, the issues you mentioned can be solved with an appropriately architected Ruby system. Provide more details about how it's architected and people can help you.

Comment: @MarkThomas You are right its an opinionated question majorly based on the scenario of the application. Let me edit the question to add more thoughts into it.

Comment: You may want to try Resque with the resque-retry plugin. If they are small jobs you may also want the resque-multi-job-forks plugin. (And resque-kubernetes for scaling if you really need it)

Comment: Just to add another option there. Have you looked at open scheduling solutions? [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_job_scheduler_software) created a simple list, some are open source and may fit your need of parallelization and dependency management.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, I would give a try to Pentaho Data Integrator (PDI) (or Talend).

They where visual tools designed to solve problems like yours. And have a free version downloadable form [SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pentaho/files/Data%20Integration/) (just unzip and press the spoon.bat button).

They can a acquire data from FTP and HTTP (among others), decode JSON, and write databases like Postgres. PDI has a free plug-in able to run Ruby code out-of-the-box, so you can save start-up development.

The PDI also has ready made Spark and Hadoop interfaces, so you can implement your hadoop/sparkle servers transparently at a later stage if you need a more *metal* solution.

The PDI was build for heavy data load and gives you you control on concurrency and remote servers.